# Relational Algebra Homework (Arrays/Collection?)

Tags: java, relational-algebra

My homework is called "relational algebra", and its asking me to perform the operations Union, Difference, Intersection, Join, Cartesian Product and Project on two tables in .txt files that read:

```
a  1             a 1
b  2    and      z 26
c  3             c 3
```

My initial question was basically how do i approach this project?

Below is my finished project, if there are any mistakes please let me know. Suggestions and critiques also welcome.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * ------------------------- Purpose : This class is used to create a row for a
 * two dimensional data
 * 
 * @since 06/17/2014
 * @author abass.alamnehe
 *         --------------------------------------------------------
 *         ---------------------------------------------
 */
class Table {                                                                       //Class Table
    public String getID() {                                                         //getters and setters
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        this.ID = iD;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String ID = "";
    String name = "";

    Table(String ID, String name) {                                                 //Table constructor
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class RelationalAlgebra {
    /**
     * It reads a two columns table into a two dimensional array
     * 
     * @return ArrayList
     *         <Table>
     * @throws IOException
     */
    ArrayList<Table> getTable(String fileName) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Table> T1 = new ArrayList<Table>();                           // creates an array list
        File inFile = new File(fileName);                                       // creates a file object
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);                                  // Scanner is a reader class

        int repetition = 1;                                                     // used to skip the 1st line from input file
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {                                             // reads until not data
            if (repetition == 1) {                                              // if 1st line, skips
                scanner.next();
                scanner.next();
                repetition = 2;
            } else {                                                            // else reads each column
                String ID = scanner.next();
                String name = scanner.next();
                T1.add(new Table(ID, name));
            }
        }
        scanner.close();                                                       // close input stream
        return T1;                                                              // returns the new table in the form of ArrayList
    }

    /**
     * It prints the content of an ArrayList
     * <Table>
     * 
     * @param t
     */
    void printTable(ArrayList<Table> t) {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(t.get(i).ID + "\t" + t.get(i).name);
        }

    }
    /**
     * It prints the content of an ArrayList into a Cartesian Product 
     * <Table>
     * 
     * @param t
     */
    void printCartProdTable(ArrayList<Table> t) {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.size() - 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(t.get(i).ID + " " + t.get(i).name + "\t");
            System.out.print(t.get(i + 1).ID + " " + t.get(i + 1).name + "\t");
            System.out.print(t.get(i + 2).ID + " " + t.get(i + 2).name + "\t");
            System.out.println(t.get(i + 3).ID + " " + t.get(i + 3).name + "\t");
        }
    }
    /**
     * It prints the content of an ArrayList 
     * <String>
     * 
     * @param t
     */
    void printProj(ArrayList<String> t) {                                 
        for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(t.get(i));
        }

    }

    ArrayList<Table> intersect(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                  // method intersect, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                      // creates an instance of ArrayList, result

        /* Checks each object, "Table", in both ArrayLists (t1 against t2)
         *  for equality at both ID and Name , ignores case,
         *  adds matches to res 
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < t1.size(); i++) {                                               
            for (int j = 0; j < t2.size(); j++)
                if (t1.get(i).ID.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        t2.get(j).ID.toString())
                        && t1.get(i).name.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(                          
                                t2.get(j).name.toString()))
                    res.add(t2.get(j));

        }
        printTable(res);                                                                   //prints table. printTable method
        return res;                                                                        //returns result (ArrayList)

    }

    ArrayList<Table> join(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                // method join, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                  // creates an instance of ArrayList, result

        /* Checks each, "Table", at corresponding key (t1 against t2)
         *  for equality at both ID and Name, ignores case,
         *  adds matches to res 
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < t1.size(); i++) {

            if (t1.get(i).ID.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    t2.get(i).ID.toString())
                    && t1.get(i).name.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                            t2.get(i).name.toString())) {
                res.add(t2.get(i));
            }

        }
        printTable(res);
        return res;                                                                     //returns result (ArrayList)
    }

    ArrayList<Table> union(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                  // method union, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                  // creates an instance of ArrayList, result

        /*  Adds all of t1 to res. Checks each object
         *   in both ArrayLists (t1 against t2) for equality at
         *   both ID and Name , ignores case, adds non-matches
         *   to res at corresponding key
         */

        res.addAll(t1);
        int c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < t1.size(); j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < t2.size(); i++) {

                if (t1.get(i).ID.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        t2.get(j).ID.toString())
                        && t1.get(i).name.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                t2.get(j).name.toString()))
                    break;

                else if (i == t2.size() - 1) {
                    res.add(j + c, t2.get(j));
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        printTable(res);                                                                         //prints table. printTable method
        return res;                                                                             //returns result (ArrayList)
    }

    ArrayList<Table> differenceAB(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                   // method differenceAB, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                          // creates an instance of ArrayList, result

        /*   Checks each object
         *   in both ArrayLists (t1 against t2) for equality at
         *   both ID and Name , ignores case, adds t1's non-matches
         *   to res 
         */

        for (int i = 0; i < t1.size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < t2.size(); j++) {

                if (t1.get(i).ID.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        t2.get(j).ID.toString())
                        && t1.get(i).name.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                t2.get(j).name.toString()))
                    break;

                else if (j == t2.size() - 1) {
                    res.add(t1.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        printTable(res);                                                                             //prints table. printTable method
        return res;                                                                                 //returns result (ArrayList)
    }

    ArrayList<Table> differenceBA(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                       // method differenceBA, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                              // creates an instance of ArrayList, result

        /* Alternate for above method. 
         *   Checks each object
         *   in both ArrayLists (t1 against t2) for equality at
         *   both ID and Name , ignores case, adds t2's non-matches
         *   to res 
         */

        for (int j = 0; j < t1.size(); j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < t2.size(); i++) {

                if (t1.get(i).ID.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        t2.get(j).ID.toString())
                        && t1.get(i).name.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                t2.get(j).name.toString()))
                    break;

                else if (i == t1.size() - 1) {
                    res.add(t2.get(j));
                }
            }
        }
        printTable(res);                                                                                     //prints table. printTable method
        return res;                                                                                         //returns result (ArrayList)
    }

    ArrayList<Table> cartProdBA(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                                 // method cartProdBA, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                                      // creates an instance of ArrayList, result
        for (int j = 0; j < t1.size(); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < t2.size(); i++) {

                /* Distributes ID and name of each table t2,
                 *  across each table t1. ((Adds new table to
                 *  res; each name and ID from t2 with each t1 name and ID))
                 */

                res.add(new Table(t2.get(j).ID, t1.get(i).ID));
                res.add(new Table(t2.get(j).ID, t1.get(i).name));
                res.add(new Table(t2.get(j).name, t1.get(i).ID));
                res.add(new Table(t2.get(j).name, t1.get(i).name));
            }
        }
        printCartProdTable(res);                                                                    //prints table. printCartProdTable method
        return res;                                                                                 //returns result (ArrayList)

    }

    ArrayList<Table> cartProdAB(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                             // method cartProdAB, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                                  // creates an instance of ArrayList, result
        for (int j = 0; j < t1.size(); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < t2.size(); i++) {

                /* Alternate for above method. 
                 *  Distributes ID and name of each table t2,
                 *  across each table t1. ((Adds new table to
                 *  res; each name and ID from t2 with each t1 name and ID))
                 */

                res.add(new Table(t1.get(j).ID, t2.get(i).ID));
                res.add(new Table(t1.get(j).ID, t2.get(i).name));
                res.add(new Table(t1.get(j).name, t2.get(i).ID));
                res.add(new Table(t1.get(j).name, t2.get(i).name));
            }
        }
        printCartProdTable(res);                                                                    //prints table. printCartProdTable method
        return res;                                                                                 //returns result (ArrayList)
    }

    ArrayList<String> projectID(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                         // method projectID, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                              // creates an instance of ArrayList, result
        ArrayList<String> proj = new ArrayList<String>();                                           // creates an instance of ArrayList, proj

        /* Makes union of t1 and t2 in res.
         * Adds each ID from res to proj. 
         */
        res.addAll(t1);
        int c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < t1.size(); j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < t2.size(); i++) {

                if (t1.get(i).ID.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        t2.get(j).ID.toString())
                        && t1.get(i).name.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                t2.get(j).name.toString()))
                    break;

                else if (i == t2.size() - 1) {
                    res.add(j + c, t2.get(j));
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            proj.add(res.get(i).ID);
        }
        printProj(proj);                                                                            //prints table. printProj method
        return proj;                                                                                //returns proj (ArrayList)

    }

    ArrayList<String> projectName(ArrayList<Table> t1, ArrayList<Table> t2) {                       // method projectName, accepts Arraylists of Tables (t1,t2)
        ArrayList<Table> res = new ArrayList<Table>();                                              // creates an instance of ArrayList, result
        ArrayList<String> proj = new ArrayList<String>();                                          // creates an instance of ArrayList, proj

        /* Alternate for above method.
         *  Makes union of t1 and t2 in res.
         *  Adds each Name from res to proj.
         */

        res.addAll(t1);
        int c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < t1.size(); j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < t2.size(); i++) {

                if (t1.get(i).ID.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        t2.get(j).ID.toString())
                        && t1.get(i).name.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                t2.get(j).name.toString()))
                    break;

                else if (i == t2.size() - 1) {
                    res.add(j + c, t2.get(j));
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            proj.add(res.get(i).name);
        }

        printProj(proj);                                                                 //prints table. printProj method
        return proj;                                                                    //returns proj (ArrayList)
    }

    /**
     * An entry point for program execution
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RelationalAlgebra rel = new RelationalAlgebra();                           // creates an object of
                                                                                   // this class
        ArrayList<Table> t1 = new ArrayList<Table>();
        ArrayList<Table> t2 = new ArrayList<Table>();                              // creates an instance of ArrayList, t1
                                                                                  // creates an instance of ArrayList, t2
        String t1file = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter Table 1 (.txt) file location with double backslahes")      //user input to string file location, t1
                .toString();
        String t2file = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter Table 2 (.txt) file location with double backslahes")    //user input to string file location, t2
                .toString();

        t1 = rel.getTable(t1file);                                                  // creates an object based on the input file
        t2 = rel.getTable(t2file);                                                  // creates an object based on the input file

        boolean input = false;                                                    //creates exit for while loop
        String select = null;                                                       // initializes variable for switch statement
        while (!input) {                                                            //while loop to prevent crash with invalid input
            select = JOptionPane                                                    
                    .showInputDialog(
                            "Enter a number (1-9) corresponding to desired operation: \n"
                                    + " 1 = Intersection of Table 1 and Table 2 \n"
                                    + " 2 = Union of Table 1 and Table 2 \n"
                                    + " 3 = Join of Table 1 and Table 2 \n"
                                    + " 4 = Difference (Table 1 - Table 2) \n"
                                    + " 5 = Difference (Table 2 - Table 1) \n"                      
                                    + " 6 = Cartesian Product (Table 1 x Table 2) \n"
                                    + " 7 = Cartesian Product (Table 2 x Table 1) \n"
                                    + " 8 = Project 'ID' from the Union of Table 1 and Table 2 \n"
                                    + " 9 = Project 'Name' from the Union of Table 1 and Table 2 \n")
                    .toString();                                                            // takes user input for selection of operation 1-9, as string
            if (select.matches("1") || select.matches("2")                                  // tests for valid input
                    || select.matches("3") || select.matches("4")
                    || select.matches("5") || select.matches("6")
                    || select.matches("7") || select.matches("8")
                    || select.matches("9"))
                input = true;                                                               // exits while loop, if valid input
        }

        switch (select) {                                                               //switches between all 9 operation methods 
                                                                                        // according to user input, which print final results of operation
        case "1":
            rel.intersect(t1, t2);
            break;
        case "2":
            rel.union(t1, t2);
            break;
        case "3":
            rel.join(t1, t2);
            break;
        case "4":
            rel.differenceAB(t1, t2);
            break;
        case "5":
            rel.differenceBA(t1, t2);
            break;
        case "6":
            rel.cartProdAB(t1, t2);
            break;
        case "7":
            rel.cartProdBA(t1, t2);
            break;
        case "8":
            rel.projectID(t1, t2);
            break;
        case "9":
            rel.projectName(t1, t2);
            break;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from what you've been given in class, what have you attempted by yourself?

Comment: Basically nothing, besides

Comment: RelationalAlgebra rel = new RelationalAlgebra() ; 
  ArrayList<Table> t1 = new ArrayList<Table>() ; 
  ArrayList<Table> t2 = new ArrayList<Table>() ;
     ArrayList<Table> union = new ArrayList<Table>();
  
                                                      t1 =rel.getTable("C:\\Users\\Renny\\Documents\\T1.txt") ;                                                     t2 = rel.getTable("C:\\Users\\Renny\\Documents\\T2.txt") ;         for (int i = 0; i<t1.size(); i++){
   union.add(t1.get(i));
   if (!t1.get(i).equals(t2.get(i)))
    union.add(t2.get(i));
   rel.printTable(union);
     
  }

Comment: 1. Put that code in your question. 2. Things to consider: Does the algebra you are implementing distinguish empty relations based on heading, or are its relations just sets? Can there be 0 attributes? Did you handle empty relations? Do you prevent meaningless unions, differences, intersections and products? PS That code doesn't union.

Comment: @JMMM "@" only works in comments. (But I checked in for progress.)

Comment: What was the exact problem statement? You should almost certainly be writing opertors that take ArrayList< Table >s and returning them. Ie i/o of tables entirely separate from operations on them. Also your question has no question.

Comment: @philipxy I edited my original post to show that i finished my project and the code that I used, is that bad practice? Also by operators does that mean methods?

Comment: If you have any questions then put them in your post. If you want to know whether your solution is correct then you must put that in your post & give the problem you were to solve, or how can we determine whether you solved it? Including the details of the algebra you were to implement. There are many algebra variations; you must explain. (Java has methods, algebra has operators; although in computer langauges method, operator, function, procedure, routine & subroutine usually all mean the same general thing.)

Comment: Few things. First of all, don't encourage cheating. Second, if you found a solution to your problem, don't post it in your question. That's what the answer section is for. Also, we're not here to do debugging/verification for you. Write some tests yourself and test your own code. It's an essential skill to learn, and the sooner you get familiar with it the better. If you have **working** code, and want feedback, consider Code Review SE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data correspond to maps, not arrays nor either sets.  Java has built in map classes, the most likely for your purposes being `java.util.HashMap`.  Having the data in that form, you can do some nice things with the maps' `keySet`s and `entrySet`s.  Among the things you can do with the latter is iterate over all the entries in the map (key and value), either via its `iterator` or by use of the fact that it is `Iterable`; you will need to do that for your joins (and your simple iteration), but you can find simpler approaches to intersection, union and difference operations.

Do read the Javadocs for `Map` and `Set`.

Comment: Okay, i'll give Maps a try

Comment: @JIMM & JohnBollinger: It is reasonable to have a tuple (array slice) be a Map and have a collection like Set of them represent the relation. Then Map iteration is over attribute name-value pairs and collection iteration is over tuples. But it is not appropriate to use a Map for the array/relation collection because the Map key (with the tuple as value) is unnecessary; the collection iterator acts as conceptual reference to a tuple.

Comment: @JMMM Are those to me? The only people notified without an @ are its author (question or answer) and a commenter who is the only one so far who is getting a comment from the author. (That said, I mistyped your username last comment!)

Comment: @JMMM & JohnBollinger: I was saying that JohnBollinger's table-as-map proposal was not straightforward, but that table-as-set with row-as-map is straightforward. (Relation=table, tuple=row & attribute=column.)

Comment: hey thanks for all yalls help, especially @philipxy. I will post my finished code now in my original post.